# How does SimpleWeather JS know the location to display weather details?

Tags: weather-api

I am using http://simpleweatherjs.com/  SimpleWeather JS in my project for weather widget,
i want to know, how the JS know location to display weather details?
is there any kind of license to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like SimpleWeather has gone away, no longer exists.

Comment: Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

it depends. one way is set your location by city / location name, like

```
loadWeather('Seattle','');
```

another is to use latitude and longitude, combined with a comma like

```
loadWeather('53.5688799,9.9761916');
```

you can also use javascript to get your geolocation data

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  loadWeather(position.coords.latitude+','+position.coords.longitude); 
});
```

consider that user has to allow js to read its location.

see full demo at http://codepen.io/fleeting/pen/Idsaj

for what i read simpleweatherjs is under the MIT-LICENSE. but i am not sure about the yahoo weather api license it uses...